# evaluate the integral by using polar coordinate

Tags: integration

Using polar coordinates, evaluate the integral $$
\int\int_R\sin(x^2 + y^2)dA
$$ where R is the region $1\le x^2 + y^2\le 64$

Comment: What is the shape of $1 \leq x^2 + y^2$? What is the shape of $x^2 + y^2 \leq 64?$

Comment: I do not know what do you mean

Comment: If you draw the region $x^2 + y^2 \leq 64$ on the x-y plane, what does it look like?

Comment: I think that it would look like a circle but i am not sure

Answer (score 2):

Make the change of variable $(x,y)=(r\cos t, r\sin t)$ into the integral, using 
$dA = dxdy = rdrdt$:

$$
I = \int\int_R \sin(x^2 + y^2) dA \\= \int_{t=0}^{2\pi}\int_1^{\sqrt{64}=8} \sin(r^2) rdrdt
\\= {2\pi}\int_1^{8} \sin(r^2) rdr \\= {\pi}[-\cos(r^2)]_1^{8} = {\pi}(\cos 1 - \cos 64) 
$$

Comment: something wrong with that, I think that your limits are wrong!

Comment: I made the edit!